# Block "Would you like to remember this password ?" popup in firefox

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk

i am creating a firefox addon using sdk and i would like to know if there is any way to block the "Would you like to remember this password ?" popup shown by firefox password manager when logging into a website. I have tried "autocomplete" attribute but it looks like firefox has stopped supporting it from version 30. It should not show up while logging in to a website. Please advice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `popupshowing` event listener and if it's the id of the password baloon, do `event.preventDefault(); event.stopPropagation()` to stop it's showing.

Or you can specifically target the baloon, by getting the id of it then attaching it like this:

For example:

```
var win = Services.wm.getMostRecentWindow('navigator:browser');
var PUI = win.document.getElementById('i dont know the id');

var previt = function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
PUI.addEventListener('popupshowing', previt, false);
```

This code attaches just to the most recent navigator browser window, you will want to iterate through all navigator browser windows, and also listen and attach to newly opened navigator:browser windows.

Comment: I tried this. But it returned "Services is undefined". So i had to replace it with " Cc["@mozilla.org/appshell/window-mediator;1"].getService(Ci.nsIWindowMediator); " But i need this to be done in my contentscriptfile. So, i cannot require Cc and Ci.

Comment: Content scripts can't access any elevated/SDK functions so there is no way to do it directly there. If you need to programatically decide to suppress the popup based on something happening on the page you'll need to send a message back to your main extension code and suppress it there.

Comment: I tried "   document.addEventListener("popupshowing", function(event) { event.preventDefault(); },false);    " in contentscript which attaches to the login page . . but it did not work. . event.stopPropagation() also did not work.

Comment: @MojoJojo get `Services` by going `var {Cu, Ci, Cc} = require('chrome')` then do `Cu.import('resource://gre/modules/services.jsm')` at the top of your code, then you can use `Services` module

Comment: @Noitidart please edit "  var PUI = win.document.getElementById('i dont know the id');  "   to   "  var PUI = win.document   " or remove that line and replace  "  PUI.addEventListener  " with "  win.document  " . . since it the document which can call addEventListener and not the element.

Answer (score 1):

After analyse FF source code I manage to fix it by adding tree additional password fields in a form.
In that case FF can not figure out what password field to use:)

```html
<input type="password" style="display: none;"/>
<input type="password" style="display: none;"/>
<input type="password" style="display: none;"/>
<input type="password" name="pass"/>
```